# Why there is an error?

Tags: c, string

I wrote the following code block I have all the time error in the function find_brackets and  calculation. can someone explain to me how to fix it. And the two functions will function together

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void find_brackets(char str[], int len);
void calculation(char str1);

int main(void) {
    int len;
    char str1[99];
    char str[99]; // (4/2)
    printf("Enter a math exercises: \n");
    gets(str);
    len = strlen(str);

    find_brackets(str);
    calculation(str1);
}

void find_brackets(str[], len) {
    char str1[len];
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if(str[i] == '(') {
            i++;
            while(str[i] != ')') {
                str1[j] = str[i];
                i++;
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
}

void calculation(str1[], len) {
    char str[len];
    char strp[len];
    char str2[len];
    char str3[len];
    char *rev;
    int i, k, j = 0, aPos, zPos;
    int sum1, sum2;
    float sum;

    strcpy (str, str1);
    strcpy (strp, str1);

    aPos = zPos = -1;

    for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if(str[i] == '+') {
            aPos = i;
        }
        else if(str[i] == '/') {
            zPos = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(aPos != -1 && zPos != -1) {
        for(k = 0, i = zPos-1; i > aPos; --i, ++k) {
            str2[k] = str[i];
        }
    }

    rev = strrev(str2);
    printf("%s\n", rev);

    for(i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if(strp[i] == '/') {
            while(strp[i+1] != '+') {
                str3[j++] = strp[++i];
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%s\n", str2);
    sum1 = atoi(str2);
    sum2 = atoi(str3);
    sum = sum1 / sum2;
    printf("%.0f\n", sum);
}
```

Thanks for the help I appreciate it

Comment: Could you please also add what the error is?

Answer (score 1):

Function declaration is `void find_brackets(char str[], int len);` and the caller from `main()` is `find_brackets(str);` which is wrong. Where is the 2nd arg.

Also function `calculation()` has differnce in declaration and how it is invoked. Maintain a match in function formal arguments followed by callee actual arguments passed.

Answer (score 0):

```
    void find_brackets(str[],len) 
    void calculation(str1[],len)
```

please specify data type of `len` and `str[]` at function definations.

Also

```
find_brackets(str);
calculation(str1);
```

which pass one argument but you declared that with two which is also wrong.